# How to check HTTP response code in zabbix?

Tags: triggers, zabbix, http-response-codes

I have a Zabbix server 2.2 and a few linux hosts with websites. How can I get a notification from Zabbix, if the HTTP(s) response code is not 200?

I've tried those triggers without any success:

```
    {owncloud:web.test.rspcode[Availability of owncloud,owncloud availability].last(,10)}#200

    {owncloud:web.test.error[Availability of owncloud].count(10,200)}<1

    {owncloud:web.test.error[Availability of owncloud].last(#1,10)}=200
```

But nothing works. I never got an notification, that the code is not 200 anymore even it was 404, because I have renamed the index.php of owncloud to index2.php

Comment: You can define a *Required status code* in the particular step of the web scenario (see [docs](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/web_monitoring#configuring_steps)). Does that help already?

Comment: No, I already set 200 there without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. You need to specify the URL to check with file. For example like this in your web scenario:

```
    https://owncloud.example.com/index.php
```

"Note that Zabbix frontend uses JavaScript redirect when logging in, thus first we must log in, and only in further steps we may check for logged-in features. Additionally, the login step must use full URL to index.php file." - https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/web_monitoring/example

I also used following expression as trigger:

```
    {owncloud:web.test.fail[Availability of owncloud].last()}>0
```

Answer (score 2):

you have set a triggers bye Expression

```
{host name:web.test.rspcode[Scenario name,Steps name].last()}=200
```

Answer (score 2):

I configured the Application and the we the Web Scenario as followed:
if you have already configured the host go to step 1

1)  Select the host by **Configuration-> Host groups -> select host** (example server 1)

[image]

2) Go to **Config > Hosts > [Host Created Above] > Applications** and click on **Create Application**

[image]

3) Now you have to create the Web scenario with the status code check, in my case I checked status code 200. So go to  **Configuration > Hosts > [Host Created Above] > Web Scenarios** and click on **Create Web Scenario** .

Remark: you have to select the previous application created at the step 2

[image]

4) After that without click on Add button go to **Steps** window and you have to configure the host and parameters for the chek. After that click on **Add**. In my cas e check the status code 200 response for the HTTP request.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered adequately, but I will provide a very much more advanced solution that you could use for all HTTP status codes.

I've created an item that monitors all HTTP status codes of a proxy, graphs them, and then set up multiple different types of triggers to watch last value and counts in last N minutes.

The regex I used to extract all the values from a Nginx or Apache access log is 
`^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:\/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] \"(\S+)\s?(\S+)?\s?(\S+)?\" (\d{3}|-) (\d+|-)\s?\"?([^\"]*)\"?\s?\"?([^\"]*)\"?\s`

I then set many triggers relevant for my particular situation

- 101 Switching Protocols
- 301 Moved Permanently
- 302 Redirect
- 304 not modified
- 400 Bad Request
- 401 Unauthorised
- 403 Forbidden
- 404 Not found
- 500 Server Error

It's also important that your Zabbix agent has permissions to read the log file on the host. You can add the zabbix-agent to the www-data group using this command.

`$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data Zabbix`

See the tutorial for all the steps in greater detail.

[image: Zabbix Log File Monitoring - HTTP Status Codes]